# How do disable MMC Command Queue Engine

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-parameters

What is the kernel parameter to disable the Command Queue Engine driver?

I am reading through [mmc.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/mmc/core/mmc.c?id=v6.5-rc1)

```c
MMC_DEV_ATTR(cmdq_en, "%d\n", card->ext_csd.cmdq_en);
/*
* Enable Command Queue if supported. Note that Packed Commands cannot
* be used with Command Queue.
*/
card->ext_csd.cmdq_en = false;
```

I am thinking maybe setting the parameter `ext_csd.cmdq_en=false`
I tried this `sdhci.debug_quirks=0x65168080` as mentioned [here](https://community.nxp.com/t5/i-MX-Processors/eMMC-message-quot-mmc2-running-CQE-recovery-quot/m-p/1232023) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the device tree has "mediatek,cqhci" property which isn't supported well by the kernel

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    mmc@11230000 {
        compatible = "mediatek,mt6768-mmc";
        mediatek,cqhci;
    };
};
```

So I had to modify the device tree file with fdtput.

```
fdtput -d /path/to/fdt /mmc@11230000 "mediatek,cqhci"
```

Steps

1. I dumped the device tree blob from the boot.img
2. [Binwalked](https://manpages.org/binwalk) the blob to get the pure flattened device tree
3. Deleted the cqhci enabler property from the blob